# How to quickly generate all tuples of N length that contain X 1's

Tags: python, list, binary, permutation

I'm trying to make a Python function that generates all possible tuples of length N that contain exactly X "1"s. For example, if I wanted all possible tuples of length 4 that contain exactly 2 ones, it would output (1,1,0,0), (1,0,1,0), (1,0,0,1), (0,1,1,0), (0,1,0,1), and (0,0,1,1).

The obvious way to do this is to simply generate *all* possible tuples of length N and then ignore the ones where `sum(tuple)!=x`, such as:

```py
def all_tuples(length, x):
  output = [0 for y in range(length)]
  while not all(output): #yield states until all bits are 1s
    if(sum(output) == x):
      yield tuple(output)
    #now, increment the "output" as if it was binary
    for x in range(length):
      if(output[x]):
        output[x] = 0
      else:
        output[x] = 1
        break
```

...However, I am trying to do this with lengths of ~40, which makes it completely unfeasable to test every single possible tuple. Is there a way to do this in some way faster than O(2^N)?

Comment: In the case of N=4 X=2, start with `0b0011` and shift the leftmost bit one place left one place at a time, then do the same with the next bit, and so on until you end up with `0b1100`.

Comment: N=4 is not the problem, finding N>30 in a reasonable amount of time is the problem.

Comment: Sigh. I was merely exhibiting it for N=4, X=2. You can generalize the procedure to N=anything you like, X < N. Surely this is obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Python function that generates all possible tuples of length N that contain exactly X "1"s:

```py
from itertools import permutations

def generate_tuples(N, X):
    if X > N or X < 0:
        return []

    indices = [1] * X + [0] * (N - X)
    tuples = set(permutations(indices, N))
    return tuples
```

The function `generate_tuples` first checks if X is within the valid range (0 to N inclusive). If X is invalid, an empty list is returned.

Next, a list of indices is created with X number of 1s and N - X number of 0s. The permutations function from the itertools module is used to generate all possible tuples from the indices list.

Finally, the resulting tuples are returned as a set to eliminate duplicates.

Here, is the use of this function:

```py
N = 4
X = 2
result = generate_tuples(N, X)
print(result)

# output: {(0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)}
```

However, Generating all possible tuples of length N with exactly X ones does indeed have a time complexity of O(2^N). However, if N is large, this approach becomes impractical.

One way to optimize the process is by using a combinatorial approach based on binomial coefficients.

Here's an updated version of the function using the combinatorial approach:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def generate_tuples(N, X):
    if X > N or X < 0:
        return []

    tuples = set()
    for comb in combinations(range(N), X):
        tuple_ = [0] * N
        for index in comb:
            tuple_[index] = 1
        tuples.add(tuple(tuple_))

    return tuples
```

In this approach, we iterate through all combinations of indices for the ones. For each combination, we create a tuple with N zeros, and then set the corresponding indices to ones. This way, we generate only the required tuples instead of all possibilities.

This approach has a time complexity of O(C(N, X)) instead of O(2^N), which is much more efficient when N is large.

Comment: for the combination approach you don't need sets and lists and you can have a generator directly like in OP's code: `for c in combinations(range(N), X): yield tuple(int(i in c) for i in range(N))`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

def unique_perms(series):
    output = set()
    for p in permutations(series):
        output.add(tuple(p))
    return output

print(sorted(unique_perms([0,0,1,1])))

# Output: [(0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Since you want to generate permutations with exactly X 1's, you can generate permutations for the same. Among all generated permutations, we only want unique entries, so unique_perms function stores the permutations in a set which will remove duplicates.

Also the problem in hand required to go over all permutations, its not possible to solve it in lesser time complexity